# Creating Excel sheet for Content Porting(component for respective pages and its path's)

Tags: 2011, 2013, core-service, cme, content-porter-2013

For content porting I am creating an Excel spreadsheet manually, but it is too time consuming. I am planning to develop an app which would give us a list of components and the respective path as per level (in steps). Is there any better or faster solution other than this, as developing this might consume time?

Or

As my  Excel document contains pages,component by levels(parent/child) can we get whole data till depth(schema) by using any coreservice api's(UsingItemsFilterData,WhereUsedItemFilterData,ResolvedItems,ItemsFilterData etc).if so Which is preferable among all.please suggest.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you Content Porting a few items or thousands?  I've found that when doing lots of items, if it is possible, a full DB backup and refresh is more time effective and provides a better result.  Just need to coordinate with all users of the system, and possibly provide a backup of the Dev / ACC DB (and maybe system too) to access newer content in Dev that needs to be restored back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an extension you can try called the Release Manager: http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/Releasemanager.aspx.  It allows for tagging an item in Tridion for a release and then creates the export xml file based on the tagged list of items.

Another option is to use Tridion 2013 Bundles. Will Price wrote about that here: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/simple-release-management-with-sdl-tridion-2013-and-bundles

Comment: +1 for Bundles - together with the support for blueprint in Content Porter 2013, seems to me like the easiest way to control this.

Comment: @NunoLinhares :one question, is there any way by which will get all component resolved in pages,and component linked to component of the pages.like deep search for pages up to nth level(till schema)

Comment: Content porter resolves all dependencies before exporting (unless you tell it not to), not sure I understand your question. If you port a page, then CP will export the components and any managed dependency those components have - schemas, linked components, etc - and since 2013 SP1 those dependencies will be exported from the "owning" publication for each item.

Answer (score 0):

```
    i  used below code to get all component(till some levels) from page
      UsedItemsFilterData filter = new UsedItemsFilterData();
                filter.ItemTypes = new ItemType[] { ItemType.Component };
                XElement xmllist= client.GetListXml("tcm:aaa-bbbb-64", filter);
                //to get list of all component for pages(Level1)
                list = (xBundles.DescendantNodes()).ToList<XNode>();
                foreach (XElement foo in list)
                {
                    if (foo.HasAttributes == true)
                        {
                            XElement xmllist2= client.GetListXml(foo.FirstAttribute.Value,filter);//get all component from component(level 2)
                            List<XNode> List2 = new List<XNode>();
                            List2 = (xmllist2.DescendantNodes()).ToList<XNode>();
                            foreach(XElement foo1 in List2)
                                {
    //repeat same loop structure to get next level
                                if (foo1.HasAttributes == true)
                                         {
                                 //for level 2
                                         }     
                                 }

                  }  
                } 
  to export it to excel i used below link...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811143/export-datatable-to-excel-with-open-xml-sdk-in-c-sharp
```